# App crashing when scrolling TableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

My app is crashing when i scroll my TableView. First in my viewDidLoad method a load a dictionary from a file and for this dictionary i enumerate all keys.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

     [super viewDidLoad];

     NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];      

     path = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"currency.archive"]]; 

     banks = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];

     keys = [banks allKeys];

     // set date for last update 
     dayMonthYear.text = [banks objectForKey:@"Last Updated"];
}
```

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath i populate cells with data from that dictionary. Anyway when my app starts everything looks fine, first five rows are drawn correctly, but when i start to scroll my app crash. My idea is that the problem is with autoreleased object here, i tried to retain them and after using them to release ,but unsuccessful. DEBUGGER SHOWS THAT MY PROBLEM IS AT LINE WITH BOLD

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {      

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CurrencyTableCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = currencyTableCell;

        //don't show selected cell
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        //set height
        self.cellHeight = cell.frame.size.height;
    }    

    // Fetch currency 
    NSString *currentCurrency = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDictionary *fetchedCurrency = [banks objectForKey:currentCurrency];

    **NSString *name = [fetchedCurrency objectForKey:@"Currency Name"];**

    currencyTitle.text = name;

    NSString *charCode = [fetchedCurrency objectForKey:@"Code"];

    currencyCode.text = charCode;

    NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",[[fetchedCurrency  objectForKey:@"Value"] floatValue]];

    if ([formattedNumber length] == 4) {
        formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"0",formattedNumber];
    }

    buyPrice.text = formattedNumber;

    return cell;    
}
```

Comment: Are path,keys,and banks property of the class?If you have set @property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray keys; etc... you have to initiate these vaules with self.keys=yourValue;

Comment: 2011-10-05 17:29:06.213 Exchanged[7112:b303] -[NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4bab9c0

Comment: has `banks` a retain property?

Comment: probably the `[banks objectForKey:currentCurrency];` returns string instead of a dictionary. Can you check this?

Comment: BTW: In order to reuse cells, you should have a static (e.g. not changing!) CellIdentifier: `NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell"`

Comment: @tilo , yes it has, but i already tried to acces it as a property;

Comment: Try this: `NSDictionary *fetchedCurrency = (NSDictionary*)[banks objectForKey:currentCurrency];` and/or `NSLog(@"%@",[[banks objectForKey:currentCurrency] class]);`

Comment: but now i get error to next field : name

Comment: Did you NSLog before or after casting it to a NSDictionary?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4036/discussion-between-tilo-and-mancunianetz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result from the discussion, `[banks objectForKey:@"Last Updated"]` gives you a NSString, not a NSDictionary!

You could get around this error by doing

```
if ([[banks objectForKey:currentCurrency] class] == [NSDictionary class]) { 
    ... rest of the code here .. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your viewDidLoad with below code it will work

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];      
     path = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"currency.archive"]]; 
     banks = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path]];
     keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[banks allKeys]];
     // set date for last update 
     dayMonthYear.text = [banks objectForKey:@"Last Updated"];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> -[NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x4bab9c0

Your banks and keys variables aren't retained, as mentioned in another answer, but this isn't the error.

As per this error, your `fetchedCurrency` object is an `NSString`, not an `NSDictionary`.  Check the format of your currency.archive file.